# find and manipulate string

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a string of path from url that I need to manipulate in order to find the actual page within the website.

so in the url I have this

**www.example.com/news/business/Royal baby - Kate gives birth to boy-201306251551**

I'd like to have something that finds the "201307231551" at the end of the url, then put it before the news title in the url. So ideally, I'd get

**www.example.com/news/business/2013/07/23/15/51/Royal baby - Kate gives birth to boy**

Can someone help please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your original URL contains "201306251551" instead of "201307231551". I assume this is a typo? Also, if you know there's a fixed length sequence at the end of the URL, there are [native string methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string_methods.aspx) which will make it quite easy to extract this value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for the topic URL Rewriting for you ASP.NET version.
Then, from the string:

> www.example.com/news/business/Royal baby - Kate gives birth to boy-201306251551"

you can use a Regex like: `(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})`. Each group represents the portion of information you need.

good luck.

---

Used the site http://regexhero.net/tester/ as helper.

```
string strInputstring = @"www.example.com/news/business/Royal baby - Kate gives birth to boy-201306251551";
string strRegex = @"(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})";
RegexOptions myRegexOptions = RegexOptions.None;
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, myRegexOptions);

foreach (Match myMatch in myRegex.Matches(strInputstring))
{
  if (myMatch.Success)
  {

    //myMatch.Groups[0].Value  <-  contains 2013.
    //myMatch.Groups[1].Value  <-  contains 06   
    //myMatch.Groups[2].Value  <-  contains 25   
    //myMatch.Groups[3].Value  <-  contains 15   
    //myMatch.Groups[4].Value  <-  contains 51   

  }
}
```

Comment: You threw a regex at someone who is unfamiliar with string manipulation? They're going to _need_ more than luck.

Comment: Yeah, especially since Kate's already supposed to be in labor.

Comment: Michael is right，I'm not familiar with regex at all. found some examples online about 'Regex.Replace', but how I can modify '201307231551' to /2013/07/23/15/51/ after regex matches?

Comment: I have updated the answer to make it more helpful.